# array.sort() не понимает украинские буквы Є и І

Tags: javascript, массивы

Имеется простой массив имен на украинском языке, в котором имена сортируются в алфавитном порядке например:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
array = ["Володимир","Іван","Богдан","Євген","Андрій"];
array.sort();
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i]);
}
</script>
```

Все сортируется отлично за исключением имен которые начинаются с украинских букв Є и І — такие имена почему то ставит первыми. Как сделать чтобы они были на нужном месте?

Comment: а если `locale` на сервере прописать? `uk_UA.UTF-8`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нашел ответ на англоязычной версии StackOverflow:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
array = ["Володимир","Іван","Богдан","Євген","Андрій"];
function uaSort(s1, s2) {
    return s1.localeCompare(s2);
}
var sorted = array.sort(uaSort);
console.log(sorted);
</script>
```

Comment: В IE10- [не работает](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Answer (score 2):

Сортировка выполняется на основании кодов символов с учётом регистра.

Для изменения порядка сортировки надо написать свой компаратор. Как вариант, сложить алфавит в отдельную строку, приводить аргументы к нужному регистру и сравнивать индексы в искомой строке. Естественно, этот способ медленный и имеет смысл его как-то улучшить, но я не знаю украинский алфавит.

---

Если выполнить на странице википедии такой код

```
var res = {};
document.querySelector("#toc ~ table").textContent.match(/(.)(?= \1)/gi).map(function(x,i) { res[x]=i+1 })
console.log(JSON.stringify(res))
```

То получится такой объект:

```
{"А":1,"Б":2,"В":3,"Г":4,"Ґ":5,"Д":6,"Е":7,"Є":8,"Ж":9,"З":10,"И":11,"І":12,"Ї":13,"Й":14,"К":15,"Л":16,"М":17,"Н":18,"О":19,"П":20,"Р":21,"С":22,"Т":23,"У":24,"Ф":25,"Х":26,"Ц":27,"Ч":28,"Ш":29,"Щ":30,"Ь":31,"Ю":32,"Я":33}
```

После приведения строки к верхнему регистру, для двух букв-ключей надо сравнивать значения.

Comment: См. [украинский алфавит](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Украинский_алфавит)

Comment: @stckvrw, ты действительно считаешь, что это я должен должен делать?

Comment: Здесь никто ничего не должен, только если есть время и желание