# Помогите сделать сортировку по алфавиту

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста сделать правильно сортировку по алфавиту, так чтобы пункт меню с value="" (отображающий список без фильтрации) - Все языки был вверху (под selected). Возможно ли так? Пример кода:

```
<select class="facetwp-dropdown form-control" id="list_languages">
<option value="anglijska" selected="">Английский (1)</option>
<option value="arabska">Арабский (1)</option>
<option value="">Все языки</option>
<option value="rosijska">Русский (1)</option>
<option value="ukrayinska">Украинский (1)</option>
<option value="farsi">Фарси (1)</option>
<option value="frantsuzska">Французский (1)</option>
</select>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(document).on('facetwp-loaded', function() {

        var t = $('#list_languages option:selected').val();
$('#list_languages').html($('#list_languages option').sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.text == b.text ? 0 : a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1;
}))
$('#list_languages').val(t);



     });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот, попробуй такой вариант:

```
    var $items = $('#list_languages option');
  var lists_sort = jQuery.makeArray($items);
  lists_sort.sort(function(a, b) {

    if ( a.value == 'all' ) return -1;
    if ( b.value == 'all' ) return 1;
    let compA = a.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    let compB = b.innerHTML.toUpperCase();
    return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
  })



  $('#list_languages')
    .html(lists_sort)
    .find('option:eq(1)').attr('selected', true);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYoWOG

В общем суть такая:
приводите к массиву, сортируете массив, приводя буквы к единому формату. При этом, проверяете (как удобно), если все языки, поднимаете вверх.
Дальше добавляете этот список в select
option:selected - я выбрал второй - т.е. первый после Все языки.

Comment: Спасибо! Но работает, только если французский выбрать. А никак нельзя фильтровать по пустому value? Дело в том, что сайт мультиязычный. На английском будет All languages, на украинском Всі мови

Comment: `if ( b.value == '') return 1;`

Comment: поставьте в value all - например

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BYoWOG

Comment: нет, не работает. В вашем примере, при клике на Все языки, отображается Французский и не меняется ни в списке, ни в url (на сайте)

Comment: ну там стоит сортировка, на change. зачем вам это. я поменял условия сортировкм. всё работает

Comment: Большое спасибо! Почти идеально:)  Но с двумя украинскими названиями языков не получилось. Почему-то букву і считает выше А https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMQzQp

Comment: ну наверное потому что для вас это И, а для кода, это другой язык.
просто возьмите, и сравните в консоле "А" > "І" и "А" > "Б" . будет наглядно видно

Comment: И вообще, странно что у вас так всё вперемешку

Comment: нагуглил решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/458998/array-sort-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%8B-%D0%84-%D0%B8-%D0%86 только помогите плиз адаптировать - return s1.localeCompare(s2);

Comment: lists_sort.sort(function(a, b) {

    if ( a.value == 'all' ) return -1;
    if ( b.value == 'all' ) return 1;
 
    return a.value.localeCompare(b.value);
  })

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvazEd